# If today's date is between startDateTime and endDateTime select only one row else select all row

Tags: sql-server

How can this be achieved in many ways? any way possible Without using if EXISTS
I want to achieve this
If today's date is between startDateTime and endDateTime
(select only one row per mobile number)
else
(select all row)
Please Help

```
Table settings
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  id  |  Gateway   |   startDateTime           |        endDateTime      |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  1   |   com1     | 2018-05-1 00:00:00.000    | 2018-05-30 23:59:59.000 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------


 Table Order
-------------------------------------------------------------
|  id  |  Gateway   |    mobile   |           Date          |
-------------------------------------------------------------
|  1   |   com1     |    222088   | 2018-05-17 10:15:54.047 |
|  2   |   com1     |    212409   | 2018-05-17 11:20:22.047 |
|  3   |   com1     |    227263   | 2018-05-17 12:53:42.047 |
|  4   |   com1     |    222088   | 2018-05-17 13:48:32.047 |
|  5   |   com1     |    212409   | 2018-05-17 14:43:12.047 |
|  6   |   com1     |    212409   | 2018-05-17 15:27:11.047 |
|  7   |   com1     |    222088   | 2018-05-18 15:15:54.047 |
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

Expected Output .Festival discounts days

```
-------------------------------------------------------------
|  id  |  Gateway   |    mobile   |           Date          |
-------------------------------------------------------------
|  2   |   com1     |    212409   | 2018-05-17 11:20:22.047 |
|  3   |   com1     |    227263   | 2018-05-17 12:53:42.047 |
|  7   |   com1     |    222088   | 2018-05-18 15:15:54.047 |
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

Example tables and data

```
declare @settings table(id int ,Gateway nvarchar(80),startDateTime 
DATETIME,endDateTime DATETIME);
insert into @settings  values 
(1,'com1','2018-05-1 00:00:00.000','2018-05-30 23:59:59.000')
declare @Order  table(id int ,Gateway nvarchar(80),mobile 
nvarchar(80),endDateTime DATETIME);
insert into @Order values (1,'com1','222088','2018-05-17 10:15:54.047'),
                       (2,'com1','212409','2018-05-17 11:20:22.047'),
                       (3,'com1','227263','2018-05-17 12:53:42.047'),
                       (4,'com1','222088','2018-05-17 13:48:32.047'),
                       (5,'com1','212409','2018-05-17 14:43:12.047'),
                       (6,'com1','212409','2018-05-17 15:27:11.047'),
                       (7,'com1','222088','2018-05-18 15:15:54.047')
----select * from @settings
---- select * from @Order

if EXISTS ( select * from @settings where GETDATE() >= startDateTime and 
GETDATE() < endDateTime )
select*from
(select a.* , row_number() over (partition by mobile order by Gateway asc) 
as hn
from @Order a
)a
left join
(select b.* ,row_number() over (partition by Gateway order by Gateway asc) 
as hn
from @settings b
)b on a.Gateway = b.Gateway 
where a.hn = 1
else 
select * from
(select a.* , row_number() over (partition by mobile order by Gateway asc) 
as hn
from @Order a
)a
left join
(select b.* , row_number() over (partition by Gateway order by Gateway asc) 
 as hn
 from @settings b
)b on a.Gateway = b.Gateway
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely there might be different ways as you've mentioned, but this is the simplest way that came to my mind:

```
;WITH CTE_ORDER
AS
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY mobile ORDER BY Gateway ASC) AS hn
    FROM @Order
),
CTE_SETTING
AS
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Gateway ORDER BY Gateway ASC) AS hn
    FROM @settings
)
SELECT * FROM CTE_ORDER AS o LEFT JOIN CTE_SETTING AS s ON o.Gateway = s.Gateway
WHERE GETDATE() BETWEEN s.startDateTime AND s.endDateTime AND o.hn = 1
UNION
SELECT * FROM CTE_ORDER AS o LEFT JOIN CTE_SETTING AS s ON o.Gateway = s.Gateway
WHERE GETDATE() NOT BETWEEN s.startDateTime AND s.endDateTime
```